# What does $f^{\leftarrow }$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions

[image]

Hello
I came across this notation and I don't understand it.

Would you be so kind to help me?

Thank you very much to all

Comment: Have you tried with more than one pdf reader? Different readers don’t always display mathematics properly so you may be experiencing that in your viewer.

Comment: @Clayton: It’s a standard notation for the preimage of a set.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! I had never seen the notation before. Is it common to use it specifically for sets? I think the only distinction I see in the use of the two notations is that one acts on a single element as opposed to a set. (I’ve always used/seen $f^{-1}$, in reference to either a set or a single element).

Comment: @Clayton: In my experience it is used only for sets, so that if $f:A\to B$ is a function, then $f^{\leftarrow}$ is a function from $\wp(B)$ to $\wp(A)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I wouldn't call it "standard". When something is standard, very few people use others notations, but I'm pretty sure that $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}[A]$ are more used than this one.

Comment: @jjagmath: It is **a** standard notation: one of several. Yes, it is probably the least common, but it is standard in the sense that it is not an idiosyncratic usage by the author of the passage, and it is likely to be encountered by anyone who reads at all widely in some areas of mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is a subset of the codomain of $f$, $f^{\leftarrow}(A)$ is the preimage of $A$ under the map $f$:

$$f^{\leftarrow}(A)=\{x\in\operatorname{dom}(f):f(x)\in A\}\,.$$

Judging by the context, the author is using $\langle c,d\rangle$ to mean the open interval that I would write $(c,d)$, i.e., the set of $x$ such that $c<x<d$, so

$$f^{\leftarrow}(\langle c,d\rangle)=\{x\in\operatorname{dom}(f):c<f(x)<d\}\,.$$

This notation does not require $f$ to be injective or to have an actual functional inverse, though the author’s use of $f^{-1}(c)$ indicates that in this case $f$ **does** have a functional inverse. That means that in this case

$$f^{\leftarrow}(A)=\{f^{-1}(a):a\in A\}\,.$$

This is one of several standard notations; I prefer $f^{-1}[A]$, with square brackets to indicate that I’m taking the preimage of the set under a function that may not have an actual inverse.

Comment: Wow, that's very kind of you.

Comment: @davidhernandez: Glad it helped.